# gtk sharp multiple styles for one widget

Tags: coding-style, gtk, gtk#

I was trying to create two different kinds of buttons: buttons with background and buttons without background.
And unfortunately I can't figure out how I can set some buttons to use the first style and some buttons to use the second.
Here's a code sample (although i doubt it'll help)
Is there some way to change the Style of the button in the .cs file, or any workaround?

```
//init hyperlink


    Button hyperlink = new Button();

    Label hyperlink_label = new Label();

    hyperlink_label.Text = hyperlink_text;

    hyperlink_label.ModifyFg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(0,0,0));

    hyperlink_label.ModifyFg(StateType.Prelight, new Gdk.Color(255,255,255));

    hyperlink_label.ModifyFg(StateType.Selected, new Gdk.Color(255,255,255));

    Pango.FontDescription hyperlinkFontDesc = new Pango.FontDescription();

    hyperlinkFontDesc.Family = "Adobe Garamond Pro";

    hyperlinkFontDesc.AbsoluteSize = hyperlink_fontSize * Pango.Scale.PangoScale;

    hyperlink_label.ModifyFont(hyperlinkFontDesc);

    hyperlink.Add(hyperlink_label);

    mainWindowFixed.Put(hyperlink, hyperlink_pos[0], hyperlink_pos[1]);





    //init startbutton

    Button startButton = new Button();

    Label startLabel = new Label();

    startLabel.Text = startButton_text;

    startButton.Settings.ThemeName = "Ludwig_AutoUpdater";

    startLabel.ModifyFg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(255,255,255));

    startLabel.ModifyFg(StateType.Prelight, new Gdk.Color(255,255,255));

    startLabel.ModifyFg(StateType.Selected, new Gdk.Color(255,255,255));

    Pango.FontDescription startLabelFontDesc = new Pango.FontDescription();

    startLabelFontDesc.Family = "Klavika bd";

    startLabelFontDesc.AbsoluteSize = startButton_fontSize * Pango.Scale.PangoScale;

    startButton.Add(startLabel);

    startButton.Child.ModifyFont(startLabelFontDesc);

    startButton.SetSizeRequest(startButton_size[0], startButton_size[1]);

    mainWindowFixed.Put(startButton, startButton_pos[0],startButton_pos[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the style of Gtk.Button. Create a custom widget derived from Gtk.Button and change that widget's style. For example:

```
 public class BGButton : Gtk.Button {}
```

and

```
 public class NoBGButton : Gtk.Button {}
```

and now change the style of BGButton and NoBGButton.
Then if you want a Button with a Background use `BGButton` , else use `NoBGButton`.